# Stop cookie to destroy on browser close

Tags: php, cookies

I am implementing stay signed in functionality on log in. When i close browser, my cookie is also deleted. How can i prevent this? I want to store cookie permanently. I don't to delete cookies

I don't want to destroy php cookies on browser close or on computer shut down. I want to permanently save cookies

I am using following code

```
$cookieExpiryTime = time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
setcookie('staySignedInEmail',encode_decode($loginQueryRes['email'],1),$cookieExpiryTime);                      
setcookie('staySignedInPassword',$loginQueryRes['password'],$cookieExpiryTime);
```

Comment: Still not got answer. anyone have any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a lifetime for your cookies..

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */ //<--- Increase the time limit there
```

The `3600` is the total number of seconds the cookie can exist. You can increase the limit there.

[`Source : PHP Manual`](https://www.php.net/setcookie)

---

**`EDIT :`**

The fixed code.. Go with this !

```
$cookieExpiryTime = time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
setcookie('staySignedInEmail',encode_decode($loginQueryRes['email'],1),$cookieExpiryTime);
```

Comment: i am setting cookies in this way $cookieExpiryTime =  time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);

Comment: setcookie('staySignedInEmail',encode_decode($loginQueryRes['email'],1),$cookieExpiryTime);

Comment: You have an error on your second line.. try this `setcookie('staySignedInEmail',encode_decode($loginQueryRes['email'],1),$cookieExpiryTime);`

Comment: i don't want to destroy php cookies on browser close or on computer shut down. i want to permanently save cookies

Comment: problem is i loss my cookie when i close my browser

Comment: I understand.. But the code you gave has a syntax error. Use the code I gave you on the answer.

Comment: I think you might be looking for [persistent sessions](http://www.paulsrichards.com/2008/07/29/persistent-sessions-with-php/).